# AS3 Panda Tea Cups (Recursive parsing, tagging, and regexp)

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, parsing, recursion

Okay, that title was an attention grabber. I'll admit that.
Now to the question!

OVERVIEW
I have some code in a project I'm working on that tags text with HTML tags (for a Flash wiki). I've created a separate file that is self contained which I'll be focusing on in this question to make things clearer.

WHAT I WANT TO DO
My input is a list of keywords and a block of text. In this case the input is

```
["panda","tea","tea cup","panda tea cup"];
```

and

```
"Tea is good. I like tea cups, too. Pandas also like tea but need special panda tea cups to drink it.";
```

The expected output should be this:

```
"<Tea> is good. I like <tea cups>, too. <Panda>s also like <tea> but need special <panda tea cups> to drink it.
```

THE PROBLEM
I thought I'd be able to do this with a simple replace() function, but soon realized that I would end up with this:

```
"<Tea> is good. I like <<tea> cups>, too. <Panda>s also like <tea> but need special <<panda> <<tea> cups>> to drink it."
```

Which I don't want.

I eventually decided to build a recursive function that breaks the code up starting with the longest keywords and working its way down to the smallest keywords. Though now I am utterly confused and keep getting recursiveParse errors.

THE FULL CODE

```
//Setup
var kw:Array = ["panda","tea","tea cup","panda tea cup"];
var s:String = "Tea is good. I like tea cups, too. Pandas also like tea but need special panda tea cups to drink it.";
var openTag:String = "<<";
var closeTag:String = ">>";
var tS:Array = [];
//Sort by length (longest to shortest)
for (var i:int = 0; i<kw.length; i++) {
    for (var j:int = kw.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
        if (kw[j - 1].length < kw[j].length) {
            var temp:String = kw[j - 1];
            kw[j - 1] = kw[j];
            kw[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
//Parse
tS[0] = s;
s = recursiveParse(s);
var n:int = 0;
function recursiveParse(m:String) {
    var tP = kw[n];
    if (m.length == 0) {
        return "test";
    }
    var p:RegExp = new RegExp(tP,"gi");
    m = m.replace(p,openTag + "$&" + closeTag);
    tP = "[<>]";
    p = new RegExp(tP);
    var b:Array = m.split(p);
    var fI:String = "";
    n++;
    for each (var f in b) {
        if (f.length > 0) {
            tS[tS.length] = recursiveParse(f);
        }
    }
    return fI;
}
trace(s);
```

Thank you in advance for your excellent answers!
Keep in mind I don't care about the code above to any extent. If your answer is a simple three line fix to the code or your own thirty three line code disregarding my work, I am fine with that. As long as the input gets turned into the output.

UPDATE:
Okay, I realize now that stackoverflow is hiding my angle brackets. Gotta fix that.
UPDATE:
Angle brackets fixed.

Comment: "tea" and "tea cup" contain "tea", is there a priority, or can notions be tagged several times?

Comment: There is no priority. My intention is to handle them completely separately. Check the expected output in the Question description for a better explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you don't need to use recursion. First, make sure your array your searched strings in decreasing order of complexity:

```
var kw:Array = ["panda tea cup","tea cup","panda","tea"];
```

That is, if string A contains string B, then A must come first. Then, you can use this regex: `/(panda tea cups|tea cups|tea|panda)/i` or, in your case, do:

```
var p:RegExp = new RegExp("("+kw.join("|")+")","gi");
```

And replace the matches by `<$&>`, as you do now.

You can see this regex in action [here](http://regexr.com?3248o).

Comment: This is... brilliant. I've wasted too much time in non-regexp. Damn. Damn. Damn. Thank you.